# Where is it mentioned that Hanuman is an Avatar of Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, avatars, hanuman

Is it true that "Hanuman is Lord's Shiva Avatar" is a medieval suggestion?

Where is it mentioned that Hanuman is Lord's Shiva Avatar?

I ask about: whether "Hanuman is Lord's Shiva Avatar" is a medieval suggestion or not?, And if not, where is it mentioned?

Comment: In the Shiva purana. I will add that there is also a refence that Hanuman is an avatar of Pavan.

Comment: @Ketan it answers my question partially, not completely. I ask also about if it is a medieval suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It's mentioned in [Shiva Purana: Śatarudra-saṃhitā: Chapter 20 - The Incarnation of Hanūmat and his story](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226416.html):

> 37. Indeed he [Hanuman] was the Incarnation of Śiva the lord and uplifter of devotees. He was the life-saviour of Lakṣmaṇa and the destroyer of the arrogance of all Daityas.

**Hanuman Chalisa** also mentions Hanumanji as son of Anjani, Keshari and son/incarnation of Vayu and Shiva:

> राम दूत अतुलित बल-धामा । **अंजनि पुत्र पवनसुत** नामा ।। (2)
>
> **शंकर सुवन केसरी नंदन** । तेज प्रताप महा जग बन्दन ।। (6)